# CNN for multi-label image classification

Tags: keras, classification, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I would design a CNN that classifies 8x8 image blocks. Specifically, I have `num_classes` equals to 40 and each image can be associated either to just one class or two classes or three classe or four classes, and so on, and even all the 40 classes.

My question is related to the loss function and metric: indeed, I want to impose that my CNN returns the `K` most confident classes, and if at least one of them is corrrect, then I want the accuracy increases

For example, suppose the simpler case `num_classes=4` and `K=2`:

```
    true = [1 0 0 0]; predicted = [1 0 1 0] OK
    true = [1 1 0 0]; predicted = [0 0 1 1] WRONG
```

So, I've already tested the following code line, but it does not what I want.

```
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which `loss` and `metric` am I supposed to use? Or maybe does it make more sense if I write my own metric function?

Comment: I guess you'll have to write your own loss and metric, but it won't be easy since the loss needs to be differentiable.

Comment: Really it does not exist a built-in function that operates in this way?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could probably start by writing only the metric (easier) and train using `binary_crossentropy` loss.

Answer (score 0):

You `compile` seems fine. For `Multilabel` networks you should also use `sigmoid activation` and **not** `softmax` to your last `dense layer` (don' t know what you are using)

```
x = Dense(40, activation='sigmoid')
```